# Could not connect to the database. Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details

Tags: database, connection, sugarcrm

I have a problem installing SugarCRM 6.5,  i get following message:

> Could not connect to the database. Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details

when i check logs i see the following statement:

> Jul  4 16:09:06 2012 [18887][-none-][FATAL] Could not connect to DB
>   server localhost as sowieso. port : Access denied for user
>   'sowieso'@'localhost' to database 'my_database_name'

I installed this on my shared hosting package and it didn't work.

My DB credentials (user name and password) are correct.

Please help to identify issue? Everything is working fine on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh install, "Could not connect to the database" is usually a result of incorrect permissions.

Our mature system has generated this error a couple of times. Rebooting the sugarcrm server cured it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your DB service is starting at the time of fsck check/or at boot time which may not able to access respective data files. Wait for sometime and restart your DB service which will fix it.